# PyGame and Unicode - a neverending story

Tags: python, unicode, pygame

What I do in my code:

1st I load a UTF-8 textfile (yes, double/triple/quadruple checked: it IS UTF-8) by using with codecs.open...

```
def load_verbslist(folder, name, utf_encoding):
    fullname = os.path.join("daten", folder, name)
    if utf_encoding:
        with codecs.open(fullname, "r", "utf-8-sig") as name:
            lines = name.readlines()
    else:
        name = open(fullname, "r")
        lines = name.readlines()
    for x in range(0, len(lines)):
        lines[x] = lines[x].strip("\n")
        lines[x] = lines[x].strip("\r")
    return lines
```

From that file come my solution strings. I later split the lines and encode everything again to blit it to the screen like this:

```
class BlittedText():
    def __init__(self, number, colour):
        self.number = number
        self.colour = colour
        if self.number == 0: #Infinitiv
            self.content = Solution.verb[0]
            self.content = self.content.encode("utf-8")
            self.text = Main.font1.render(str(self.content), 1, self.colour)
            self.pos = (45, 45)
```

Then I append a list named "Strings" by several of those BlittedText() classes.

Then I blit it to the screen:

```
for element in Strings:
    screen.blit(element, position)
```

The result can be seen in this picture:
http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/6617/ee43.png
In the Python shell (left side) everything shows correctly, my inputs (very left side) as the strings from the solution TXT file (which definitely, surely, 100% is saved as UTF-8). On the screen my input (black) blits correctly, while the solution strings (green and red) show weird characters instead of the unicode characters. I thought, I properly encoded them but obviously not :/

Does anyone find my mistake? Where's my thinking gone wrong?

Thank you very much already!

Pat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't encode the string to `utf-8` before rendering.
When you encode it to utf-8 you are generating a regular string with strange characters.

If you encode it to latin-1 you get rid of the strange characters:

```
self.content = self.content.encode("iso-8859-1")
```

Comment: I thought so too, but if I don't I get the "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)" error :/

Comment: Parhaps the render() method is encoding to standard ascii producing an error. I think you should encode it to "iso-8859-1" (latin-1) instead of utf-8 that way you get rid of the strange characters and you get support for the entire latin-1 charset. I hope all your characters are latin-1.

Comment: Thank you! That works and seems like the characters are really all in Latin-1. It still doesn't make sense to me, because my input is also encoded in UTF-8 and contains the very same characters too - and they are blitted with no problems at all...

Comment: The source in utf-8 is a good solution, but once loaded in python it loads as a unicode string (2 bytes per character), if you encode that to utf-8 you get a regular string (1 byte per character) but the non ascii characters (non-english) are splitted in two characters, then pygame has no way to detect that it has to interpret that as an utf-8 string (perhaps you just want to render strange characters).
What doesn't make sense to me is that pygame fails to render unicode strings, but you have a work around! Good luck.