# blit function to render a utf-8 string across the screen

Tags: python, utf-8, pygame, blit

I have written a pygame script that renders a horizontally moving text across the screen. It works, but when I change the string to a non-latin string (Persian), it does not work completely. I mean it does everything (animation, rendering ...) but the characters are depareted from each, though they are shown healthy, but are not in the expected order. I mean each letter is shown well, but a word is not rendered, a sequence of characters are rendered.

the string should be`سلام`
but it is rendered `م ا ل س`

Here is the full code:

```
import sys, pygame; #importing the required modules

#initialize the game module
pygame.init();

#setting the display properties and put in a variable
width = 800; #px
height = 600; #px
display_info = (width, height);
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display_info);

# adding contents
arial = pygame.font.SysFont("Tahoma", 21);
text = arial.render("سلام", 1, (233,114,93), (255,255,255));
clock = pygame.time.Clock();
x = 0;
#starting the game loop
while True :
    #it sets the timing of the loop-execution (40 fps)
    clock.tick(40);

    #getting the list of event on each game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get() :

        #if the event is QUIT (if the user has acted to close the application)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT :
            pygame.quit(); #terminate python-side
            sys.exit(); #exits system-side

    #refreshing the screen with overall blackness
    screen.fill((0,0,0));

    #rendering the text. We do not move the text, we just increment the position on each loop
    screen.blit(text, (x, height/3));

    #incrementing the x-position
    x += 1;

    #updating the display to the latest changes
    pygame.display.update();
#end of the while loop
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyGame and Unicode - a neverending story](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415639/pygame-and-unicode-a-neverending-story)

Comment: There is no solution there. I have checked it and done the answer, but nothing changed to good but a collection of totally strange characters

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that my characters are non-latin

Comment: make sure the font you're using (Tahoma) supports your language's chars!

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/61/arabic-isnt-shown-correctly) in `pygame` and is currently classified as "won't fix", because:

> To support all languages, we'd need to include a much larger font file, and changing files would break existing games.

One user in the thread suggests that [`python-fribidi`](https://github.com/behnam/python-fribidi) can be used to get the correct behaviour.