# How to draw str(non-latin-word) in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm only learning to program , so my question can be trivial . Sorry for that !

I want a programm to draw a word (in russian) on screen using Pygame . And that is ok, everything is working :

```
# coding=utf-8
import pygame,sys

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

some_font=pygame.font.Font(None,30)

word_to_print=some_font.render(u'привет',True,(255,255,255),(0, 0, 0))

while 1:
        screen.blit(word_to_print,(0,0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()
```

But when i try to draw the same word, but in this form :

```
some_font.render(str('привет'),True,(255,255,255),(0, 0, 0))
```

=> output is strange looking rubbish (something like that ÐÐµÑ ÑÐ°).

I got two questions :

1) how to get  my program to drow str(any word in russian) ?

2) why is it working like that ?

Comment: Have you seen e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17415639/3001761

Comment: Yes i read it , but i do not know how to use it in my code . I don't understand what should i .encode('iso-8859-1') . I would be grateful if you could show me on my code .

Comment: Where does the "*any word in russian*" string come from? Are you reading it from a file? Are you fetching it from a database? Is it a literal string in your source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > 1) how to get my program to draw str(any word in russian) ?

Strictly speaking, you can't. If you want to display arbitrary Russian text, you should store that text in a `unicode()` object, not a `str()` object:

```
unicode_string = u'привет'
some_font.render(unicode_string, ...)
```

If you don't have access to the original `unicode()` string, but only have the encoded `str()` string, you can decode it, if you know the encoding:

```
str_string = 'привет'
unicode_string = str_string.decode('utf-8')
some_font.render(unicode_string, ...)
```

If the object to which you apply `str()` is not already a `str()` (see your comments below), then you can call `unicode()` instead:

```
unicode_string = unicode(my_object)
some_font.render(unicode_string, ...
```

Finally, if the object to which you apply `str()` does not provide `.__unicode__()` method, but does return an encoded `str()` string, you can decode that string if you know the encoding:

```
str_string = str(my_object)
unicode_string = str_string.decode('utf-8')
some_font.render(unicode_string, ...
```

> > 2) why is it working like that ?

From the [pygame docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render), "Both Unicode and char (byte) strings are accepted. For char strings a LATIN1 encoding is assumed." You have passed a `utf-8`-encoded string to a method that requires a `latin1`-encoded string.

Comment: But i cannot use 'u' with str() . 
str(u'привет') is not working (UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: ordinal not in range(128))

Comment: Why do you want to use `str()`?

Comment: I want to print instance of some object , whose method __str__ is like str('привет')

Comment: Does the object implement a `__unicode__` method? If not, do you have control over it, so that you could implement `__unicode__`?

Comment: Yes i can implement ! Thank you , i'll do it .

Answer (score -1):

The default font for font.Font doesn't support many non-Latin characters. If your using windows 10, you can find fonts on your computer in C:\Windows\Fonts, but they must be of type .ttf (not .ttc). If you don't have a font of the right file-type that supports the languages characters then you can easily download one online. Also, for some reason, when I downloaded an online font, it couldn't be used from the windows font folder, I had to keep it in a separate folder and use font.Font to access it there.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the OP's question about drawing a string using Pygame.